# NSMutableArray addObjects - unrecognized-selector

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, addition, unrecognized-selector

This is how I initialize my NSMutablearray. I copy the content of cityList into cityArray. Both are NSMutableArray. FYI, I declared the'cityArray' using extern.

```
cityArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[cityArray addObjectsFromArray:cityList];
```

Then, in other method in another class, I tried to to add one more object into 'cityArray' This is how I do it. But it keep crashing when it run this line of code.

```
NSString *allCities = @"All Cities";
[[cityArray valueForKey:@"cityName"] addObject:allCities];
```

This is from the console '[__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6292de0''.

But if I test it with setvalue:forkey:, it works but that is not what I want. I want the new data to be added into the bottom of the list.

Comment: why [[cityArray valueForKey:@"cityName"] addObject:allCities];
? You can use [cityArray addObject:allCities];

Comment: because in city array also cityID property which I will need it later..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `NSArray` doesn't implement `valueForKey:`. Your want either an `NSDictionary` or use `objectAtIndex:`.

Your second section of code should read:

```
NSString *allCities = @"All Cities";
[cityArray addObject:allCities];
```

Comment: NSMutableArray also doesn't implement this method.

Comment: Then how should  go about this? How to add another row in this kind of array?

Comment: Use addObject: or use a NSMutableDictionary. You could also create a City Class where you can store your cityId and name and store an instance of this class in your MutableArray.